# Changing between two instances of MetalLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

Is it possible to have two different instances of `MetalLookAndFeel` and change between them at runtime? I'm designing a theme engine for an IDE called MARS(MIPS Assembly IDE) and I either need a custom look and feel that will allow me to manipulate each and every component's colors or I will use the default `MetalLookAndFeel` with `UIManager` to change colors.

I looked at Java's own implementation of`LookAndFeel` but didn't understand how I could do it. There are no tutorials out there to follow if one wants to write a `CustomLookAndFeel`, so I came up with a solution like that.

Is it possible to have two instances of `MetalLookAndFeel`, one with altered colors and one is the default, and switch between them at runtime? If not, what can be done to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed nice to hear. But what I'm asking is: **Is it possible to have two instances of the same `LookAndFeel` and switch between them?** The program you linked switches between different `LookAndFeel`s, not exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Yep, my bad. I couldn't see the forest for the trees. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an idiot and not understanding how Inheritance actually works causes some problems... The solution is simple. Subclass `MetalLookAndFeel` and use the `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(String className)` to switch between the original `MetalLookAndFeel` and the subclass `CustomLookAndFeel`.

The subclass `CustomLookAndFeel`:

```
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;

public class CustomMetalLookAndFeel extends MetalLookAndFeel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5415261270648192921L;
}
```

The `Main Method`(Needs `InvokeLater` and such but I'm too lazy):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UIManager.installLookAndFeel("CustomMetal", "laf.CustomMetalLookAndFeel");
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("laf.CustomMetalLookAndFeel");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Panel.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.RED));

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JButton j = new JButton("100000");
    j.addActionListener(e -> {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(f);
    });
    p.add(j);
    f.add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Plus one for not only figuring it out, but reporting back.